# What is the minimum possible score

Tags: algorithms

There are n players numbered 1 to N who play against each other till one of them wins.
Initially  all the players have score 0.
In a game when a player with score x defeats a player with score y his score changes to 1 + max(x,y) .The player who gets defeated can no longer play any games.

All players are defeated in one or the other game except for player 1. To be precise, player i is defeated in some game by some player A[i-1] in 0 based indexing. A player is not defeatedd untill he defeats all the players he can.

A different sequence of game may lead to different final score of the player 1.

Then what would be the minimum possible score of player 1.

Input:

First line: integer N.

Next N-1 lines: ith line contains an integer A[i] representing player i+1 was defeated by player A[i].

Example :

```
5
1
1
2
4
```

There can be many sequences in which battles are fought. Here is one that generates minimum score for God 1.

In the 1st battle, God 4 and 5 had a battle, and God 4 won. His score is 1.

In the 2nd battle, God 2 and 4 had a battle, and God 2 won. His score is 2.

In the 3rd battle, God 1 and 3 had a battle, and God 1 won. His score is 1.

In the 4th battle, God 1 and 2 had a battle, and God 1 won. His score is 3.

You can not devise any other timelines of battle that results in a score less than 3 for God 1.

Hence

Output:

```
3
```

I am not getting any idea how to solve this.

Can anybody help me in this. I think we have to use dynamic programming in it.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum possible score is obtained when one does a tournament of rounds.  The score works out to $\lceil log_2(N)\rceil$

The maximum possible score is obtained by a new player playing the winner of the last contest.  The score works out to $N-1$